# Is it possible to read non-text files into a google dataflow pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to read pdf files into the pipeline. However, I haven't found any apache beam example regarding file formats other than plain text or xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-existing PDF reader available in Dataflow or Apache Beam libraries.  However, you could use the example of this reader for TensorFlow records as a model to write your own using the PDF parsing library of your choice.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TFRecordIO.java

Comment: Thanks for the link Andrea.

Comment: Do you know of such an example in Python?

Thanks, eilalan